# CSS hover Slider - Unable to complete

Tags: html, css

I want to do the following hover slider:

[image]

The blue part should slide from left to right when hovered on the red part. It should slide from the right part of the red part and not showing (i.e. should be sliding behind the red part). Blue part should initially be hidden behind the red and should not show at all The blue part will be bigger than the red part so it had to be hidden with overflow or something else. There should be no opacity transitioning, however other transitioning is acceptable

This is what I have thus far:

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="static-content">
  </div>
  <div class="overlay">
    OverLay Content - this will be some text
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;

  .static-content {
    display: block;
    background-color: red;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }

  .overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color: #008CBA;
    height:100%;
    width: max-content;
    transition: .5s ease;
  }
}

.container:hover .overlay {
  transform: translateX(100%);
  height: 100%;
}
```

Problem is blue part is infront of red part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this to `.overlay` element `z-index: -1;` to make it behind the red
div

and if the red div is smaller so it doesnt hide it all then u can but transparent colored div at the part that u want to hide since u dont want to do it with overflow

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean that I do not want to use overflow. I can use overflow if that is the best solution. I am gona edit my question quickly.

Comment: If you edit your question with the solution to hide it with overflow I can mark it as the answer

Answer (score 1):

You can give your blue div style a z-index to take it under the red one like this :

```
.overlay {
      position: absolute;
      z-index: -1;
      top: 0;
      right: 0;
      background-color: #008CBA;
      height:100%;
      width: max-content;
      transition: .5s ease;
    }
```

Comment: That solves half of the problem. thnx. But another problem is the overlay block is still sticking out on the left side since the overlay will be bigger than static-content container depending how much text you put in it and I want to make this a re-usable component.